# Shibboleth SP not returning to proper server when using GCP load balancer with path rules

Tags: shibboleth-sp

I think I have a bit of a unique situation here. I have the following setup:

Server A set up with Shibboleth SP and using Google SAML as an IDP.
Server B set up with Shibboleth SP and using the same shibboleth2.xml files and Google SAML as an IDP as Server A.

Both servers are behind a google load balancer.
Server A get any default traffic and Server B get traffic based on load balancer path rules.
web.com/...  ->  Server A
web.com/abc  ->  Server B

If I send traffic to Server B, I can see Shibboleth SP kick in and request authentication. After authentication I can see traffic return to Server A at which point it just returns the homepage of Server A. It does not get back to Server B where it came from.

I have tried the following settings:

```
**<StorageService type="Memory" id="mem" cleanupInterval="900"/> <SessionCache type="StorageService" StorageService="mem" cacheAssertions="false" cacheAllowance="900" inprocTimeout="900" cleanupInterval="900"/> <ReplayCache StorageService="mem"/> <ArtifactMap artifactTTL="180"/>**


**<Sessions lifetime="28800" timeout="18000" checkAddress="false" consistentAddress="false" handlerURL="/Shibboleth.sso" handlerSSL="false" cookieProps="http" relayState="ss:mem" exportLocation="http://localhost/Shibboleth.sso/GetAssertion" exportACL="127.0.0.1" idpHistory="false" idpHistoryDays="7">**
```

Any thoughts on if this is even possible would be appreciated.
Thanks